# Preserve leading whitespace when reading YAML file from _data in Jekyll

Tags: yaml, jekyll, whitespace

I am trying to made a code block on my Jekyll website but I cannot preserve whitespace properly.

I am using a YAML file in my _data file to display certain data on my website.

Here is what I have in my YAML file:

```
Sample Title:
  type: Script
  description: "Description of script"
  code: "for(double i = Start; i < End; i += 1){

    display();

  }"
```

And in one of my Jekyll layouts (titled: card.html) I have:

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="content">
    {{page.card.description | markdownify}}
      <h2>Script</h2>
        <pre><code>{{page.card.code}}</code></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have kramdown installed and on my _config.yml

When I do this, whitespace is not preserved on my website. I get this, in a codeblock:

```
for(double i = Start; i < End; i += 1){
display();
}
```

However, whitespace in-between text and leading whitespace on the first line is preserved. If I do this with my YAML file, the whitespaces in-between text and the leading whitespace on the first line is preserved.

```
  Sample Title:
  type: Script
  description: "Description of script"
  code: "  for(double i =      Start; i < End; i += 1){

    display();

  }"
```

My website will look like this, note the preserved whitespace but not on the second line:

```
  for(double i =      Start; i < End; i += 1){
display();
}
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong and how do I preserve leading whitespaces on every line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use YAML's [literal style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#812-literal-style), which preserves whitespace. A minimal example of a complete page could look like

```markdown
---
layout: home
code: |
 for(double i = Start; i < End; i += 1){
    display();
 }
---

<h2>Script</h2>
<pre><code>{{page.code}}</code></pre>
```

resulting in a code block

```
for(double i = Start; i < End; i += 1){
   display();
}
```